# Rent a scooter for 2 weeks in Bali

Tags: rental, indonesia, motorcycles, bali

I want to rent a scooter for 2 weeks in Bali.

What kind of price should I expect?

I have been told that the daily price is usually 50'000 IDR. 
So I expect a discount when renting for 14 days. I just don't know how much of a discount.

Related: [Renting a motorbike from a private person in Indonesia?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/49722/9395)

Comment: Where do you start your journey? Denpasar? Denpasar is more expensive. If you can go to Lovina in North Bali, you can rent the cheaper one.

Comment: @FriendlyGhost I am in Denpasar right now and have just been offered a scooter rental for 35'000 IDR per day for 2 weeks. I saw the scooter and it looks standard to what I previously rented when in Java. Can it get much cheaper??

Comment: 35,000 rupiahs a day sounds cheap, but you can make a try, say to him, "tolong jangan mahal-mahal dong supaya saya bisa jadi langganan", it means "please make it cheaper so I can still be your customer now and forever". Try 30,000 rupiahs a day.

Comment: @pnuts yeah, sounds pretty bad I gotta say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The daily rental price varies depending on the location, demand and the condition of the units (either new or old).

For example, [sewamotordibali.com](http://sewamotordibali.com/tarif-sewa-motor-di-bali/) rent the unit with price starting from 70,000 rupiahs (for customer using it infrequently) to 55,000 rupiahs (for customer using it frequently).

Other site, for example, [www.sewamotor-bali.com](http://www.sewamotor-bali.com/p/blog-page.html) offers cheaper ones. Starting from 65,000 rupiahs daily and 430,000 rupiahs weekly (7 days a week).

Any price in Indonesia is negotiable so I am pretty sure that 40,000 rupiahs per day for 2 week rental is possible.

Another solution, you can rent from any Balinese rather than from the rental agent. It might be cheaper. But be careful, the unit might no longer be convenient because of over-engineered customization.

## Note:

Even though Bali is safer than other places in Indonesia, always double lock your bike and park at appropriate places.

Comment: Double lock your bike? Never seen any lock on any bike while in Sumatra and Java. Is this more common in Bali?

Comment: The second lock is attached to the disk brake. But be careful, don't forget to unlock before riding. You might get fallen and bend the brake disk.

Answer (score 3):

Following up on this after renting motorbikes in Bali several times.

For a 2 weeks rental, it's easy to get it around **35'000 IDR per day**, that's 490'000 IDR maximum for two weeks.

Actually, I rented a scooter for **1 month for 500'000 IDR**. So you can get this 2 weeks rental for much cheaper I assume. Another option if you don't know how long you will stay might just be to get the 500'000 per month rental and not have to worry to extend the rental (& having to renegotiate, pay extra, ...).

Here is another interesting article on the topic http://www.divergenttravelers.com/rent-scooter-bali

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you will stay, it might be the cheapest and most convenient option to rent from the hostel. But I guess this only counts for smaller venues, that are run by a family.

I also wanna note that as far as I remember it is very dangerous to ride the scooter. People are driving like crazy and if you're not used to the way they drive it can definitely get dangerous. Even amongst the balinese people there are many accidents and its the no.1 reason for people to die there.

Comment: Actually it's the 3rd highest reason... ([source](http://www.thejakartapost.com/news/2011/08/04/road-wrecks-list-bali-top-killers.html))

Comment: Oh ok.. my bad.

Comment: @Flip please stay focused on the question. I know it's tempting to go off the tangent but if you want to warn about how dangerous it is to ride a motorbike/scooter in Bali, then create a question (i.e. "is it dangerous to ride a scooter in Bali") and help answering it. Then just add a link to it, as a relevant topic ;)

Comment: By the way, you went so off topic that you don't even answer the question: how much?