# Is it possible to rent a scooter in Probolinggo?

Tags: transportation, rental, indonesia, motorcycles

Where can I rent a scooter in Probolinggo?

I tried several hotels, one guesthouse, and the tourism information (opposite Probolinggo's train station entrance) but I couldn't find anyone renting out a scooter.

Note: [this post](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/49599/9395) is a related question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Info from June 2015**

It's **very hard** to rent a motorbike in Probolinggo.

Forget about finding a **motorcycle rental** company, there is **none** at the time of writing (2015). I literally spent an afternoon trying to find one.

Your best option is to rent it from either:

1. your hotel (they provide this service sometimes) in Probolinggo
2. a private individual. Don't be shy, just ask people in shops/warungs. You will most likely be left with this option.

Here is a good thread on this topic [Renting a motorbike from a private person in Indonesia?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49722/renting-a-motorbike-from-a-private-person-in-indonesia)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about Probolinggo specifically, however most Indonesians that study in another city also rent motorbikes rather than bring their own over. Considering Probolinggo does have universities, I bet there are motorbikes for rent. However, this may not be targeted at tourists so information may be hard to find.

I know for a fact there are plenty of motorbikes for rent in Malang, which is a different approach to Bromo (Bromo being the only reason any tourist is ever in need of a motorbike in Probolinggo) but even there the market is more aimed at local students.

If you're feeling adventurous and your accommodation cannot provide for motorbikes, just go to a university and ask or look around there. Or as the other advice stated, just ask anyone. People love to make some extra money and usually can deal with missing their motorbikes for a few days.

(Source: lived in Indonesia for 2 years of which 1 year in Malang)

Comment: thanks for the "students tip" :) never heard of that before